# Register method in AngularJS is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure

I have webApi deployed in azure http://pselleruserregistration.azurewebsites.net/api/Account/Register 
when i am sending post request then it is not working but in fiddler it is working. below is the code

```
scotchApp.controller('signupController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.signUp = function () {

        return $http({

            url: 

           'http://pselleruserregistration.azurewebsites.net/api/Account/Register',

            dataType: 'json',

            method: 'POST',

            data: {

                "Email": "rrrk@gmail.com",

                "Password": "Samplestring@2",

                "ConfirmPassword": "Samplestring@2"

            },

            headers: {

                "Content-Type": "application/json"

            }

        })

    }

});
```

Comment: what do you mean by is not working? what error are you facing?

Comment: which response code you are getting?

Comment: You can leverage the develop tool of browsers, monitor the console section for the request error. Or, you can leverage the callback function in the `http` promise's next state, refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http for the complete sample. And please share your detailed error message for us.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the error you are getting is related to cross domain request.

You can not perform any ajax request to different domain until that domain gives you permission.

you need to add these header on your server side.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```